# PHP Visitor count with flock

Tags: php, visitor-pattern, flock

I am trying to use a visitor count. I have made it so it works without flock, but are trying to make it work with flock. I don't really understand where I should use flock, but have tried implement it in a file called  VisitorCount. Now I don't get any result and the website turns blank. 
What should I think about when using flock?

```
    <?php
    require "visitorCount.php";
    incrementVisitorCount();

    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo getVisitorCount();
    ?>
```

```
    <?php

    $file = fopen("visitor-count.txt", "w+");

    function incrementVisitorCount() {
        $visitorCount = getVisitorCount();

        if(flock($file, LOCK_EX)) {
            file_put_contents("visitor-count.txt", $visitorCount + 1);
            fflush($file);
            flock($file, LOCK_UN);
        } else {
            echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
        }
        fclose($file);
    }

    function getVisitorCount() {
        $visitorCount = trim(file_get_contents("visitor-count.txt"));
        return $visitorCount;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Website turns blank, probably indicates an error, did you check your logs?

Comment: I can see that you are locking a file, and then trying to write over that file with file_put_contents.  Whereas you should be using your locked file handle (that is out of scope in your function here).  Your error logs will help.